# React: Is there any way to use componentDidMount() when rendering via node server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

So I'm quite new to react and node, and found it easiest for me to use node (express) server and then just linking to react using CDN. Until now everything has worked fine this way, but I would like to use something like componentDidMount() for rendering a list of books. Googled a little and found out that componentDidMount() is not fired when rendering via the server. So I was wondering if there is an alternative way, that can do the same thing. Tried with componentWillMount() as well, but no change.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: What's your case? If it's an operation that you cannot use a constructor for, it's likely unsuitable for SSR.

Comment: was thinking to fetch data, and then displaying it on page render

Comment: Do you intend to render fetched data on server sdie?

Comment: The plan was to render on client side, i have a method in React class that sends a fetch(), method: Get request to the server that executes a query to the database and sends the response back to the client

Comment: Currently SSR is synchronous. A request likely shouldn't be coupled with a component then. Fetch it separately, pass hydration data to client side. Things are expected to change in 17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. In an isomorphic react app, `componentDidMount` will only be called after the hydration is done in the client.

So, if you want to render something based on props or state, you can use the class `constructor` or the legacy [`componentWillMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount) as these methods will be called during render done in node.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i'm getting some values from another api on componentDidMount method but i want to get values on server side and send to the client. So how do i use constructor class to achieve this?